# why the time complexity is T(n) = 2n^2 + n + 1?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

T(n) = 2n^2 + n + 1
I understand the 2n^2 and 1 parts, but I am confused about the n.

```
test = 0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        test = test + i*j
```

Comment: Even *if* the formula was `2n^2 + n + 1` (and I don't think it is), the ***time complexity*** would simply be `n^2`. You generally drop all but the most important term and remove constant multipliers.

Comment: This cannot be answered without more context. If that is an answer given in a textbook, it may be counting some parts of the loop control, but it is unclear what. There are several things that might or might not be counted in a hypothetical problem like that: n^2 instances of `*` in `i*j`, n^2 instances of `+` in `test + i*j`, n^2 instances of `=` in `test = …`. n^2 instances of incrementing `j`, and n^2 instances of testing for the end of the `j` loop, n instances of incrementing `i`, n instances of testing for the end of the `i` loop, and 1 instance of assigning `test = 0`.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Complexity is not necessarily expressed using O notation.

Comment: @Eric, that's correct but, given one of the tags is `big-o`, I assumed that's what the OP was discussing. Of course, it may have been an errant tag based on limited knowledge. People reading my first comment should also take into account Eric's response, and then re-read mine as if I had stated "big-O time complexity" :-)

Comment: This was given in professor's lecture slides. I was totally lost on the n.

Comment: I would like to confirm that test = test + i*j is O(2) right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on how your professor/book really break down the operation cost but I think we can kind of figure it out from here. Let's break `2n^2 + n + 1` down. The `n^2` comes from the two loops.

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
```

The `2` coefficient comes from the two operations presumably. Note: this alone is just constant time complexity AKA O(1)

```
test = test + i * j
```

The initial calculation of `range(n)` could cost `n` (being the `+ n` in your calculation). Then second call to `range(n)` could be optimized to use a cached value.

Finally it could be the `test = 0` statement in the beginning could be the `+ 1`. This could total in `2n^2 + n + 1`. However, the worse case time complexity to this is still `O(n^2)`.

Comment: So if we are looking for T(n) to find the constant and n0, it actually does not matter a lot that is it 2 operations inside or 3 right?

Comment: If we're discussing big-O (worse case time complexity), not only do the constant value not matter but pretty much smaller order magnitudes don't matter much either. They can matter if you're trying to micro-optimize or if you have real world or average case data that proves slowdowns other wise. The two loops will probably end up costing you most hence `O(n^2)`. The number of operations is still roughly `2n^2 + n + 1`.

Comment: I want to note that the `range(n)` operations was the *tricky* part of the question since most  other languages you can do a for loop with a range without having to call another function.